# Setup notification for private docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I am trying to setup notification for my private docker registry. But i am getting the following error from the docker compose file

> PS C:\mydockerregistry> docker-compose up
>
> ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   Unsupported config option for notifications: 'endpoints'

Here is my docker compose file

```html
registry:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
notifications:
  endpoints:
    - name: alistener
      url: https://requestb.in/13yg1rj1
      timeout: 500ms
      threshold: 5
      backoff: 1s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach I was taking was wrong. Notifications will not go in docker-compose file but docker config file 
See sample config file https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/cmd/registry/config-example.yml
Documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#example-development-configuration

Comment: I set up URL in config.yml but I did not receive any image tag etc and req body is empty after push event..any help